# How to get respose for appopen event at parse.com

Tags: php, rest, parse-platform

I am getting blank json in response  when appOpen event is called

My code : -

```
$headers = array( 
"X-Parse-Application-Id:trPYPHrI1Cfb8Q4w3TQ5HY7RoDcOFSM4okdNWDyC" , 
"X-Parse-REST-API-Key:OeNTANdx5A6ILHIZi3NfVcuE3GPDg4Cmyo9aQM1R",
"Content-Type: application/json"
);

$data='{ }';


$rest = curl_init();
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.parse.com/1/events/AppOpened");
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$response = curl_exec($rest);
echo $response;
curl_close($rest);
```

output : { }

working url : http://norefresh.thesparxitsolutions.com/rajeevranjan/parse/appopen.php

please help.

Comment: $data is not empty. Have you passed information?

Comment: What are you expecting as a response?

Comment: @BjörnKaiser no of times app requested.

Comment: @BhumiShah data is optional,it takes date as parameter https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#analytics

Comment: if i run same code you provided, get message like {"error":"unauthorized"} so how can i check issue?

Answer (score 0):

This URL `https://api.parse.com/1/events/AppOpened`

return {} or true means your app lauched. You can check responsecode by

```
$responseCode = curl_getinfo($rest, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($responseCode);
echo "</pre>";
```

I have checked with other url `https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Player`, as it's working fine. check following code:

```
$headers = array( 
"X-Parse-Application-Id:trPYPHrI1Cfb8Q4w3TQ5HY7RoDcOFSM4okdNWDyC" , 
"X-Parse-REST-API-Key:OeNTANdx5A6ILHIZi3NfVcuE3GPDg4Cmyo9aQM1R",
"Content-Type: application/json"
);

$data='{ }';


$rest = curl_init();
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Player");
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$response = curl_exec($rest);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
curl_close($rest);
```

Comment: command 'events/AppOpened' says you'll able to collect data on when and how often your application is opened.I am able to get statistics for other like you got for 'classes/Player'.

Comment: I also contacted a developer at parse.com got a response .http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ed3toyz24    .he is also available on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/users/353988/fosco